# Slight gap between list items in an unordered list

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome

I am using an unordered list where the actual list items have a rounded rectangular background image.

My problem is, there seems to be a slight gap between the list items in Firefox but in Google Chrome, there is no gap.

If I change the CSS line-height value, it corrects in Firefox but then breaks Google Chrome.

What do I need to do? I think I am doing something wrong to ensure that between each list item, there is no gap in both Firefox and Google Chrome.

Comment: Can you post a link so we can see what it looks like?

Comment: do you have a css reset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best bet is to reset all padding/margins on your `<li>` and `<ul>` and then add padding back in as needed for the background image:

```
ul, li {
    padding: 0;  
    margin: 0;
}
```

Different browsers apply different default paddings/margins to list, so you need to strip it off for consistency.

Answer (score 4):

I came across the problem a few minutes ago and found an easy fix that hadn't yet been posted here. I tried changing the margin and the padding and that didn't work, so I floated all the LI element's left, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I've removed a broken link - please add it again if the document exists under another URL. In general, answers should not be used to point to an off-site article - put at least some of the information here if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a negative margin?

```
li { margin-bottom: -2px; }
```

These cross-browser pixel imperfections will always exist, this margin trick usually saves a lot of time when tweaking the layout.

Answer (score 0):

A negative margin value as a safety factor will solve it for you...

```
ul li {
    margin: -2px;
}
```